# What is the best way to reuse the attributes from a UIButton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uitoolbar

I have a bunch of buttons that I'm adding to a `UIToolbar` when a `UITextField` is tapped using `inputAccessoryView`. All of these buttons are identical except for the title and what I would like to be able to do is reuse the UI attributes such as `titleColor`, `frame` etc.

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish what I described above?

Here is the code...

```
    // code for first button
    let button1 = UIButton();
    button1.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    button1.setTitle("button1", forState: .Normal)
    button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button1.setTitleColor(UIColor.orangeColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
    button1.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:35, height:35)
    button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myFunction), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    // code for second button which is identical to the first button
    let button2 = UIButton();
    button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    button2.setTitle("button2", forState: .Normal)
    button2.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button2.setTitleColor(UIColor.orangeColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
    button2.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:35, height:35)
    button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myFunction), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    barButton.customView = button

    let barButton2 = UIBarButtonItem()
    barButton2.customView = button2

    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.items = [ barButton, barButton2]
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    myTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refactor the duplicate code into a single local function.

```
func configure(_ button:UIButton) {
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.orangeColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
    button.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:35, height:35)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myFunction), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

// code for first button
let button1 = UIButton()
button1.setTitle("button1", forState: .Normal)
configure(button1)

// code for second button which is identical to the first button
let button2 = UIButton()
button2.setTitle("button2", forState: .Normal)
configure(button2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 4):

Something like @matt's answer, but IMHO better:

```
// code for first button
let button1 = UIButton().configure("button1", frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35), target: self, action: #selector(myFunction))

// code for second button which is probably not exactly identical to the first button. They should at minimum have different titles, different frames and activate different functions.
let button2 = UIButton().configure("button2", frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35), target: self, action: #selector(myFunction))
```

Elsewhere in your code because you probably will use it in several view controllers:

```
extension UIButton {
    func configure(title: String, frame: CGRect, target: AnyObject, action: Selector) -> UIButton {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        self.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.orangeColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
        self.frame = frame
        self.addTarget(target, action: action, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        return self
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach too, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @fs_tigre I also like his approach but with an important tweak. Add an enum for your default case. see [this](http://www.jessesquires.com/enums-as-configs/?utm_campaign=This%2BWeek%2Bin%2BSwift&utm_medium=email&utm_source=This_Week_in_Swift_98) awesome link.